# How to show progress bar for uploading process in each row of listView one by one?

Tags: java, android

I want to set a progress bar in each row of list View.A progress bar should start or show progress for uploading files.I want to set this progress bar in each row of list view.And progress bar will be start progress one by one in each row after finishing one progress.

Comment: use a custom listview for this purpose

Comment: use an `AsyncTask<x, y, z>` with a progress dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to create a custom `ArrayAdapter`, and add a progress bar to each of the elements, you do this by adding a `ProgressBar` to the layout you inflate with. There after you'll want to catch the upload listener, so that you can listen to the progress, and update the progress bar. If you want them to upload one at a time, I suggest adding a variable to your object or make a `ArrayList<Boolean>` to check if the previous elements, has uploaded yet.

[Example of how to create an ArrayAdapter](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/)
It also shows how to create a layout, for the rows you will be inflating.